# SDN 4 + OGM 1.1.1 @Index(unique = true) is not working

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I know this question has been asked before, but looks like not with `SDN 4` and `OGM 1.1.1`

Here is my code on the `@NodeEntity`

```
@NodeEntity
public class Company {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Index(unique = true)
    private String name;

    private String description;
```

Here is the `repo`

```
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends GraphRepository<Company> {

    Company findByName(String name);
```

and I have a unit test class with methods

```
@Autowired
private CompanyRepository companyRepository;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    companyRepository.deleteAll();

    Company company = new Company();
    company.setName("Westpac");
    company.setDescription("blah");

    companyRepository.save(company);
}

@Test
public void testIndexUnique() throws Exception{

    Company company = new Company();
    company.setName("Westpac");
    company.setDescription("blah blah");

    companyRepository.save(company);
}
```

The `@Test` actually passed, which is not what I am expecting. It suppose to be failed since a `Company` with `name` field `Westpac` already exist.

Am I missing anything or understand this `@Index` wrongly.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Index isn't supported in SDN 4- http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.RC2/reference/html/#_index_management_in_spring_data_neo4j_4

or the OGM- http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm/java/stable/#_indexing

You'll have to set up the index yourself (or using Cypher via the Neo4jTemplate/Session)