# Spring Data Neo4j 4 - Create field Long with Auto Increment

Tags: neo4j, auto-increment, spring-data-neo4j-4

I want to make 2 identity of Node. One for graphId (internal id of neo4j graph id) with annotation @GraphId and second for tableId for easily declaration Id per Node (start from 1 to *)

SDN 4 is not supported @Index anymore from open question [SDN 4 + OGM 1.1.1 @Index(unique = true) is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32388724/sdn-4-ogm-1-1-1-indexunique-true-is-not-working)

Any other method how to easily make property Long or Integer with Auto Increment without using any plugin or manual code?

**UPDATE**

Create open issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-807 and waiting for next update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoincrement functionality isn't available in SDN/Neo4j-OGM. A server extension or code is the only way to do this currently.

Comment: Hmm.. So I need to do manual code or use plugin to make it. Okay @Luanne thank you. I hope Auto Increment feature will be added at future.

Comment: It would be best to add a feature request here https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH so that the product team is aware of it, thanks

Comment: Okay sure.. It will give big help to other developer too.